# Mixing C++ with Objective-C and Java

Tags: java, android, c++, objective-c, java-native-interface

Hello I noticed when calling a java method from C++ we use the JNI helper and in the method we call we must declare this , but on objective-c we don't call any equivalent to runOnUiThread ? I would like to know why this is , does it have something to do with objective-c and c++ being able to be mixed in the same file (.mm) ?

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // your code
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is right; Objective-C(++) (in contrast to Java or Swift) is interwoven with C++, and you may mix objective-c code with C++ code. The ending `.mm` file is actually a hint to the compiler that such a mix is intended. For Java and Swift, you need a "bridge" like JNI to access the other language's artefacts.

As general in Objective-C, any call from the main thread (which is the UI-thread) will be executed by default in the main thread, unless you dispatch it explicitly to another asynchronous thread. So an explicit `runOnUiThread` is superfluous.

Comment: just curious do you know what would happen if I called the java method from c++ using JNI and in the java method I did not include the runOnUiThread ? would it create a new thread to run on or would it crash ?

Comment: One you are in the java world, the system behaves according to the java world. So - once you are in any thread in the java realm - unless you explicitly launch a new thread therein you will stay in the same thread.

Comment: ok, I wonder why we have to declare for it to runOnUiThread then ?